# Type assertion on objects

Tags: typescript

Why are type assertions of objects‘ properties not “propagated” further?

```js
type Message = { text?: string };

function print(input: { text: string }) {
  console.log(input.text);
}

const message: Message = { text: 'hi' };

if (typeof message.text === 'string') {
  print(message); // does not work
    
  const text = message.text;
  print({ text }); // works
}
```

I’d expect that I can call `print(message)` after verifying that `message.text` is indeed a string, however it does not work due to `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. (2345)`. Instead I need create a new object to pass to the print function.

PS: I’m aware that I could write a type guard function for that, but it seems strange that TS cannot infer this automatically?

Comment: The answer to all these questions is: "it's hard, or it hasn't been implemented yet". Typescript gets better over time and it can already figure out a lot of things that it could not in the past.

Comment: @Evert Totally valid and not unexpected - I wanted to figure out if I'm not missing anything obvious here :-)

Comment: You're not. Also take a look at the latest 5.5 beta. Apparently it's better at narrowing some stuff